# How to use elm reactor to access files via http request?

Tags: elm, elm-reactor

`elm 0.19`

```
$ mkdir myprj; cd myprj; elm init; elm install elm/http
```

then create src/test.elm and src/test.txt:

```
$ tree
.
├── elm.json
└── src
    ├── test.elm
    └── test.txt


$ elm reactor
```

then navigate to:

```
http://localhost:8000/src/test.elm
```

so the browser window shows:

```
This is a headless program, meaning there is nothing to show here.

I started the program anyway though, and you can access it as `app` in the developer console.
```

but the browser console shows:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) test.text:1
```

Why can't `elm reactor` locate `test.txt`?

test.txt:

```
hi
```

test.elm:

```
import Http


init () =
    ( "", Http.send Resp <| Http.getString "test.text" )


type Msg
    = Resp (Result Http.Error String)


update msg model =
    case msg of
        Resp result ->
            case result of
                Ok body ->
                    ( Debug.log "ok" body, Cmd.none )

                Err _ ->
                    ( "err", Cmd.none )


subscriptions model =
    Sub.none


main =
    Platform.worker 
        { init = init
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = subscriptions
        }
```

**Solved**

In test.elm, the url "test.*txt*" was falsely spelled to "test.*text*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comment has different file extensions. You said you created `src/test.txt` but you are getting a 404 because you are asking for a `.text` extension.

Try going to http://localhost:8000/src/test.txt

Comment: I need access `test.txt`via http from `test.elm` program when it is running under `elm reactor`.

Comment: It works correctly for me when the file name in `test.elm` matches the text file name on disk. Are you certain yours match in real life as well?